# ¿ Porque cuando ejecuto mi proyecto en expo sale en blanco?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

no se que ocurre ya instale todas las dependecias y funcionan bien pero al ejecutar el proyecto sale en blanco
e intentado de todo y no visualiza ningun url

mi archivo app.js

```js
import React from 'react'; 
import { View } from 'react-native'; 
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
export default 

   function App() 
     {  
        return (    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>      
            <WebView        allowFileAccess        
            originWhitelist={ ['*'] }        
            source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/www/index.html'}}        
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}      />    
            </View>  ); 

        }
```